# How to prevent output of conditional execution tokens (/*40101 ...) in MySQL dumps

Tags: mysql

Without trying to explain why *you* think I should keep these in my `mysqldump`s, please tell me how I can prevent any conditional execution tokens (the lines that start with `/*!40101` or similar) from appearing in *my* output file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of these comments in a MySQL dump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916392/how-can-i-get-rid-of-these-comments-in-a-mysql-dump)

Comment: Gosh! Why doesn't anyone seem to have a clue about this? The thing is: if I know for sure that the restoring version will be the same as the dumping version, then these "conditionals" are nothing but absolute bloat in my dump files!

Comment: Or, @Tom, do you have a solution yet?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo I no longer deal with this issue however I believe I used regular expression to clean my files when I did.