# mysqldump skip comments

Tags: mysql

I do database dump with mysqldump command. Command that I use:

```
$mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --host=1.1.1.1 db_name
--add-drop-database --add-drop-table --skip-compact --no-data
--skip-comments --skip-set-charset --skip-dump-date --skip-tz-utc --tab=path
```

and get result:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `action`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `action` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

But I need this dump:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `action`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `action` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

how to remove those comments:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
...
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Comment: They aren't useless comments - dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916392/how-can-i-get-rid-of-these-comments-in-a-mysql-dump

Comment: I've already read this question and answers. But, anyway I must remove those comments

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916392/how-can-i-get-rid-of-these-comments-in-a-mysql-dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [post-process Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kI8wT7/1) to remove the lines since mysqldump does not support removing those comments:

`(.*OLD_SQ.*)`

with global modifier `g`.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the `--compact` option will remove these comments. You could have used this command:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --host=1.1.1.1 db_name --compact --add-drop-table --no-data
```

Complete sample output:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tester`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tester` (
  `col1` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Any argument to remove the remaining ones?

Comment: `mysqldump --help`

Comment: Pointless comment. None of the options there removes the last comments, hence my question.

Comment: If you already know none of the options can do it, why ask the question?

Comment: Probably pipe it through grep like `mysqldump ... | grep -v character_set_client` or something would be safe if it doesn't collide with a name in your database.