# Cleaner mysql dumps

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I really don't like the output that `mysqldump -R` generates.

```
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.15-5 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)
```

Consider the following setup:

```
mysql> create database testing;
mysql> use testing;
mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database,@@collation_database;
@@character_set_database        @@collation_database
utf8mb4 utf8mb4_unicode_ci
mysql> ALTER DATABASE testing CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database,@@collation_database;
@@character_set_database        @@collation_database
utf8mb4 utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts() BEGIN insert into t1 values(987); END//
mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Procedure: GetAllProducts
            sql_mode:
    Create Procedure: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetAllProducts`()
BEGIN insert into t1 values(987); END
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Now this is the dump!

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.15-5, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: example2.rds.amazonaws.com    Database: testing
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.12-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 SET NAMES utf8mb4 ;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!50717 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'performance_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'session_variables' */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_get_is_supported = IF (@rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables, 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_is_supported FROM performance_schema.session_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME=\'rocksdb_bulk_load\'', 'SELECT 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_get_is_supported */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load = IF (@rocksdb_is_supported, 'SET SESSION rocksdb_bulk_load = 1', 'SET @rocksdb_dummy_bulk_load = 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'testing'
--
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetAllProducts` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetAllProducts`()
BEGIN insert into t1 values(987); END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50112 SET @disable_bulk_load = IF (@is_rocksdb_supported, 'SET SESSION rocksdb_bulk_load = @old_rocksdb_bulk_load', 'SET @dummy_rocksdb_bulk_load = 0') */;
/*!50112 PREPARE s FROM @disable_bulk_load */;
/*!50112 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50112 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-04-26 11:42:07
```

All those lines prefixed with `/*!` seem unnecessary to me. I want to preserve my sanity by letting all the tables/views/procedures in the table assume database charset/collation defaults.

Furthermore the dump seems to have omitted my databases settings of **CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci**!

What am I missing to get better backups? Thank you

Comment: Those comments are [version dependent statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1916392), and they *are* relevant and executed  on your server (except the onces that are only executed on servers >=5.7.17, courtesy of using a mysqldump 8 for a 5.7.12 server). Removing them would certainly not make a *better* backup (just a less compatible or broken one).

Comment: Ok, though speaking of broken, my CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 & COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci are missing. Am I going crazy?

Comment: You mean for your database? Those would only be relevant if your dump would include a `create database`-statement (try e.g. `--databases testing`); the other character set settings are "hidden" in the the conditional code.

Comment: `-B` seems to be working in my backup script

Comment: You added the `SET NAMES`?  It is effectively the same as 3 of the `SETs`.  Since you are not _comparing_ strings, the `COLLATION` is [I think] not relevant.